# Is $K=\overline{\Bbb Q}$?

Tags: extension-field, splitting-field

Let $K/\Bbb Q$ be an algebraic extension. Suppose $x^n-\alpha$ splits completely in $K$, that is, all its roots lie in $K$, for all $n\in\Bbb N$ and for all $\alpha\in K$. Is $K=\overline{\Bbb Q}$?

Comment: Do you mean the closure of rational numbers, that is real numbers?

Comment: @ZelosMalum The _algebraic_ closure is something different from the analytic closure.

Comment: @ZelosMalum No, I don't: $x^2+1$ has no real roots (here, $\alpha=-1$).

Comment: Just wanted ot make sure, been far too long since I looked at the algebraic closure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're saying that $K$ is gotten from $\Bbb Q$ by adding all possible (complex) roots of numbers. This is not quite the algebraic closure of $\Bbb Q$, by the [Abel-Ruffini theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem).

For instance, $x^5-x+1$ does not split over $K$

Comment: This does not seem quite this straightforward. The field in question is the smallest algebraic extension containing those. It is not clear to me that it contains no other elements (i.e. that there is an algebraic extension containing just those).

Comment: I think Arthur is right. The upshot is the following: you first build the splitting field $K_1$ of all solvable polynomials $f(x)\in\Bbb Q[x]$, and you build by induction the splitting field $K_{n+1}$ of all solvable polynomials of $K_n[x]$. In the end, the compositum $K$ satisfies the hypothesis, but any root of $x^5-x+1$ is not in $K$.